# Onesignal fails to deliver test (and any other) notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I'd like to use onesignal for sending notifications to an already working android app created without onesignal android sdk. I successfully managed to setup an app and add one user to it (using onesignal rest api).

When i try to send a notification using GCM api at https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send, it gets successfully delivered instantly. On the other hand, when i try to send a notification from onesignal admin (to a user with the same token), it is not delivered, but the admin dashboard shows a successfull delivery. The test notification is also not delivered. Is there any way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

The GCM payload the OneSignal sends is probably not in the same format the current version of your app is expecting. OneSignal's GCM payload is as follows:

```
{
  "alert": "Message Body",
  "title": "Message Title",
  "custom": { 
             "a": {
               "customKey": "customValue"
            },
            "i":"22ac4870-c602-4fa0-b85c-400adab80e00"
  }
}
```

This OneSignal GCM format is currently fixed. I recommend adding your expected GCM format to your question and contact OneSignal support with a link to this thread.

Comment: But the notification should at least arrive, at this point i dont mind that it wont start the app,no?

Comment: Can you check that logcat to see if your getting any GCM entries? Also I recommend printing out the full GCM payload in your GCM BroadcastReceiver to make sure your app is getting it.